# User report function

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I want to implement a report feature with Django in my blog which users will be able click a link/button under a post and the admin will be notified and he will decide if the post shows up on the homepage or not .

My Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    post_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,  upload_to="images/")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | '  + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', args=(str(self.id)),)
```

My views.py

```
def LikeView(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post-detail', args=[str(pk)]))

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    ordering = ['-post_date']

class Suggest(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.annotate(like_count=Count('likes')).order_by('like_count')
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'post_list' # Providing a useful context_object_name is always a good idea

class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetail, self).get_context_data()
        current_post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        total_likes = current_post.total_likes()

        liked = False
        if current_post.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True 


        context['total_likes'] = total_likes
        context['liked'] = liked 
        return context                    
            

    

class AddPost(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
    # fields = '__all__' 
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Thanks in advance!
...................................................

Answer (score 0):

You should probably at least add another attribute to your Post model that can determine whether or not a particular post should even display on the homepage.

From there, I think you need to decide how admins will actually review these posts/set them to be visible on the homepage. It could be as simple as sending them an email and having them log into the django admin to find the post in question and set this new homepage display attribute as needed.

The email could even include a URL to the post in question directly!

For more information on sending emails from django, check this out:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/